# Linebreak in ticks-labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm using `\symbolic y coords` in a `xbar`-plot. Some of these coords are very long. There is a solution using `nodes` which is very ... hardcoded. And it would be nice to have it automated.

1. How do I generate line breaks in ticks labels?
2. Is there a way without using nodes?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=0.9\textwidth,compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,1.025)}, anchor=south,semithick,legend columns=3}}
    \begin{axis}[   xlabel=x-label,
            xbar,
            xmin=0,
            enlarge y limits=0.2,
            height=0.5\textwidth,
            ytick=data,
            bar width=7pt,
            symbolic y coords={y label 1,y label 2,very very very very very long y label 3,thelongestylabeleverwrittenasoneword},]

            \addplot coordinates
            {(5.3987,y label 1)(16.1961,y label 2)(32.081,very very very very very long y label 3)(41.9026,thelongestylabeleverwrittenasoneword)};
            \addplot coordinates
            {(2.3917,y label 1)(7.1751,y label 2)(10.153,very very very very very long y label 3)(15.5834,thelongestylabeleverwrittenasoneword)};
            \addplot coordinates
            {(0.4881,y label 1)(1.4643,y label 2)(4.361,very very very very very long y label 3)(2.7435,thelongestylabeleverwrittenasoneword)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Also, you don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: That is not an MWE. It contains many irrelevant packages. Please only include packages that are relevant for the problem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I would approach this plot a bit differently: Instead of using `symbolic y coords`, I would manually specify the labels using `yticklabels={<First>,<Second>,...}`, which makes it possible to specify the line breaks explicitly by using something like `yticklabels={Primär-\\energieverbrauch,...}`. This will only work if you also specify an `align` for the labels, by setting `yticklabel style={align=right}`, for instance.

I would also load the data into a table first, by loading the `pgfplotstable` package (which ships with PGFplots) and then using `\pgfplotstableread{<data table>}<macro name>`. You can then say `\addplot table [x=<column name>] <macro name>` to plot a column. If your data table does not contain a numerical ID field that can be used for the `y` position, you can say `\addplot table [x=<column name>, y=\coordindex] ...`, which will sequentially assign a number to each row in the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=0.9\textwidth,compat=1.4}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
Name,A,B,C
Stromverbrauch, 5398.7, 2391.7, 488.1
Primärenergieverbrauch, 16196.1, 7175.1, 1464.3
Primärenergieeinsparung, 10153, 15583.4, 4361
Kälteproduktion, 32081, 41902.6, 2743.5
}\datatable
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,1.025)}, anchor=south,semithick,legend columns=3}}
    \begin{axis}[   xlabel=Energie {[kWh]},
            xbar,
            xmin=0,
            enlarge y limits=0.2,
            height=0.5\textwidth,
            ytick=data,
            yticklabels={
                Stromverbrauch,
                Primärenergie-\\verbrauch,
                Primärenergie-\\einsparung,
                Kälteproduktion
            },
            yticklabel style={align=right},
            bar width=7pt,
            ]

            \addplot [fill=red] table [x=A,y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
            \addplot [fill=green] table [x=B,y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
            \addplot [fill=blue] table [x=C,y expr=\coordindex] {\datatable};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Generally, you can set the maximum width the labels may take up by saying `yticklabel style={text width=<length>}`, forcing the text to wrap around. It seems, however, that this doesn't work with umlauts, even if you load `[T1]{fontenc}`. Here's an example that compiles correctly with `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`, replacing the `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages with `fontspec`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=0.9\textwidth,compat=1.4}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,1.025)}, anchor=south,semithick,legend columns=3}}
    \begin{axis}[   xlabel=Energie {[kWh]},
            xbar,
            xmin=0,
            enlarge y limits=0.2,
            height=0.5\textwidth,
            ytick=data,yticklabel style={text width=3cm,align=right},
            bar width=7pt,
            symbolic y coords={Stromverbrauch,Primärenergieverbrauch,Primärenergieeinsparung,Kälteproduktion},]

            \addplot [fill=red] coordinates
            {(5398.7,Stromverbrauch)(16196.1,Primärenergieverbrauch)(32081,Primärenergieeinsparung)(41902.6,Kälteproduktion)};
            \addplot [fill=green] coordinates
            {(2391.7,Stromverbrauch)(7175.1,Primärenergieverbrauch)(10153,Primärenergieeinsparung)(15583.4,Kälteproduktion)};
            \addplot [fill=blue] coordinates
            {(488.1,Stromverbrauch)(1464.3,Primärenergieverbrauch)(4361,Primärenergieeinsparung)(2743.5,Kälteproduktion)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```