# histogram - groups stacks, histogram starts at 5

Tags: pgfplots

I've got several problems

- my groups stacks
- my histogram starts at 5 instead of 0

Any idea how to fix these problems?

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INPUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{preamble.tex}
%\input{parameters.tex}

\tikzset{graphpgf/.style={font={\sansmath\sffamily\large}, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex, x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm}}

\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/histogram/.style={
            %%%%%%%%%%  Dimensionnement de l'image  %%%%%%%%%%
            width=15cm,
            height=15cm,
            unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
            %%%%%%%%%%  esthétique des axes  %%%%%%%%%%
            axis x line = bottom,
            axis y line = left,
            %enlargelimits=false,
            line width=0.35mm,
            every major grid/.append style={black!20, line width=0.35mm,},
            every minor grid/.append style={black!10, line width=0.005mm,},
            every major tick/.append style={line width=0.4 mm, major tick length=7pt, black},
            every minor tick/.append style={line width=0.01mm, minor tick length=4pt, black},
            axis background/.style={fill=white},
            }
        }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Variable %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  Coordonnée des barres
%   (#1, #2) ==> 
%   #1=l'abscisse de la barre ; 
%   #2=L'ordonnée -(/hauteur) de la barre.

\newcommand{\listep}{(Transport en commun, 43) 
                    (Voiture, 32) 
                    (Train, 15)
                    (Vélo, 12)
                    (Marche, 23)
                    }
\newcommand{\listlab}{Transport en commun, Voiture, Train, Vélo, Marche}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[graphpgf]
\begin{axis}[
            %%%     Paramètre graphique de l'histogramme
            histogram,
            %%%     Paramètre des axes
            title style= inner sep=12pt,
            title= \Large Moyen de transport utilisés par 125 élève pour se rendre à l'école,
            yticklabels={0,5,...,50},
            %xticklabels={\listlab}, 
            symbolic x coords={\listlab},
            xtick=data,
            xlabel=Notes des élèves,
            ylabel=Nombre d'élèves,
            %xmin=0-0.5, xmax=10+0.5,
            ymin=0, ymax=50,
            %minor x tick num = 0,
            minor y tick num = 4,
            %area style,
            %xmajorgrids=true,
            %xminorgrids=true
            ymajorgrids=true,
            yminorgrids=true,
            bar width = .8cm
            ]
            \addplot+[ybar, mark=no, orange, fill=orange!50!white] plot coordinates {\listep};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: change by `symbolic x coords/.expanded=\listlab,`

My full **Preamble.tex**

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FRENCH NOTATION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[francais]{babel} % assure la bonne césure des mots français et utilise les mots français pour les dates, etc.
\DecimalMathComma % veille à ce que LaTeX ne place pas automatiquement d'espace après la virgule d'un nombre décimal
\frenchspacing % supprime les espaces additionnels suivant les points finaux
% Ouvrir le fichier frenchb.dtx dans LaTeX et produire le document frenchb.dvi pour plus d'information.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FONTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{fontspec} % permet de définir le type de police de caractère utilisé SEULEMENT EN XeLaTeX et en LuaLaTeX!
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % encodage dans le fichier source en UTF8 pour admettre les caractères accentués
% En enregistrant le fichier avec extension .tex, il faut choisir l'encodage UTF8.
% De même, en ouvrant ce fichier ("Ouvrir..."), il faut désigner l'encodage UTF8.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % encodage des caractères en 8 caractères binaires dans le fichier TeX produit (puis dans le PostScript ou le PDF)
%\usepackage{lmodern} % cette police de caractères Latin Modern est la plus souvent utilisée dans les encodages en 8 caractères binaires
% La police Latin Modern complète la police originelle Computer Modern encore largement utilisée dans TeX mais qui ne dispose pas des caractères accentués.
\usepackage{tgadventor}% paquet de police de caractère TGadventor
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{noto} % cette police de caractères est plus lisible (sans serif) que la police Latin Modern, particulièrement pour les titres ou les exercices destinés aux enfants.
%\usepackage{kpfonts} % It includes a complete set of features including mathematics as well as non-math characters and looks a little more interesting without being distracting.
%\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign} % à tester: police Garamond Expert with Math Design
%\usepackage{garamondx} % à tester: police Garamond Expert with Math Design

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MATH. NOTATION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath} % permet la création d'équations avec \begin{equation} \end{equation}
\usepackage{amssymb} % pour les ensembles de nombres (\mathbb{R}) et des symboles du type: \rightsquigarrow et \bigstar
%\usepackage{amsthm} % for the "proof" environment
\usepackage{MnSymbol} % pour l'affichage de la flèche courbe \rcurvearrowdown
\usepackage{numprint} % place des espaces entre groupes de 3 chiffres pour les nombres comportant un grand nombre de chiffres
\usepackage{graphicx}
% permet l'intégration de graphique grâce à la commande \includegraphics
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor} % A DECLARER AVANT TIKZ!
% permet l'intégration de graphique grâce à la commande \includegraphics
% xcolor permet d'afficher des images en couleurs
% le pilote pdftex permet l'intégration d'images au format JPEG, PNG, PDF. Pour utiliser des images EPS, utiliser le pilote dvips
\usepackage{tikz} % permet l'intégration des dessins TikZ (les graphiques Geogebra peuvent être exportés au format TikZ)
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Permet de tracé de graphiques
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,calc,math,shapes}

\usepackage[pdfauthor={Laurent Fourny},%
    pdftitle={},%
    bookmarks,colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{enumitem} % permet de réduire les espaces dans les environnements itemize avec l'option [nosep]
\usepackage{textcomp} % symbole € via commande \texteuro
\usepackage{comment} % pour (dé)commenter plusieurs lignes à l'aide de \includecomment ou \excludecomment
% Il faut modifier ThisComment pour éviter d'interpréter les caractères UTF8 dans les commentaires
% Voir: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159820/comment-sty-and-utf8-encoding
\renewcommand\ThisComment[1]{%
  \immediate\write\CommentStream{\unexpanded{#1}}%
}
\usepackage{cancel} % permet, dans un environnement mathématique, de tracer une barre diagonale sur une expression
```

Comment: Try `symbolic x coords/.expanded=\listlab,`. (I cannot test because the editor I am comfortable with does not like these accents.)

Comment: thx, but it doesn't fix the problem (cf. EDIT). I'm using overleaf.

Comment: It does, but there are more problems coming from `unit vector ratio=1 1 1,`, which jams the bars. Please see the answer below. (One can further improve it but I really have a hard time using an unfamiliar editor.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `symbolic x coords/.expanded=\listlab,` and undo some of the styles you install. (I can only edit this in an editor I am not comfortable with, so please forgive me when I refrain from adding too much explanations and cleaning up.)

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INPUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{preamble.tex}
%\input{parameters.tex}

\tikzset{graphpgf/.style={font={\sansmath\sffamily\large}, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex, x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm}}

\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/histogram/.style={
            %%%%%%%%%%  Dimensionnement de l'image  %%%%%%%%%%
            width=15cm,
            height=15cm,
            %unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
            %%%%%%%%%%  esthétique des axes  %%%%%%%%%%
            axis x line = bottom,
            axis y line = left,
            %enlargelimits=false,
            line width=0.35mm,
            every major grid/.append style={black!20, line width=0.35mm,},
            every minor grid/.append style={black!10, line width=0.005mm,},
            every major tick/.append style={line width=0.4 mm, major tick length=7pt, black},
            every minor tick/.append style={line width=0.01mm, minor tick length=4pt, black},
            axis background/.style={fill=white},
        xticklabel style={align=center,text width=9em}
            }
        }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Variable %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  Coordonnée des barres
%   (#1, #2) ==> 
%   #1=l'abscisse de la barre ; 
%   #2=L'ordonnée -(/hauteur) de la barre.

\newcommand{\listep}{(Transport en commun, 43) 
                    (Voiture, 32) 
                    (Train, 15)
                    (Vélo, 12)
                    (Marche, 23)
                    }
\newcommand{\listlab}{Transport en commun, Voiture, Train, Vélo, Marche}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[graphpgf]
\begin{axis}[
            %%%     Paramètre graphique de l'histogramme
            histogram,
        enlarge x limits=0.1,
            %%%     Paramètre des axes
            title style= inner sep=12pt,
            title= \Large Moyen de transport utilisés par 125 élève pour se rendre à l'école,
            yticklabels={-5,0,5,...,50},
            %xticklabels={\listlab}, 
            symbolic x coords/.expanded=\listlab,
            xtick=data,
            xlabel=Notes des élèves,
            ylabel=Nombre d'élèves,
            %xmin=0-0.5, xmax=10+0.5,
            ymin=0, ymax=50,
            %minor x tick num = 0,
            minor y tick num = 4,
            %area style,
            %xmajorgrids=true,
            %xminorgrids=true
            ymajorgrids=true,
            yminorgrids=true,
            bar width = .8cm
            ]
            \addplot+[ybar, mark=no, orange, fill=orange!50!white] plot coordinates {\listep};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Schrödinger's cat do you use a special package to render the special accent (ex: é) without any problem? Have got problem with "vélo". i'm using the package `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: @Nilcouv Guess he (Tom?) is using a unicode-capable engine, for example xelatex or lualatex.

Answer (score 0):

I approached the problem differently based on the following post : [Linebreak in ticks-labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35872/linebreak-in-ticks-labels)

[image]

**Main.tex:**

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INPUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{preamble.tex}
%\input{parameters.tex}

\tikzset{graphpgf/.style={font={\sansmath\sffamily\large}, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex, x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
%%%     Paramètre graphique des histogrammes pgfplots
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/histogram/.style={
            %%%%%%%%%%  Dimensionnement de l'image  %%%%%%%%%%
            width=15cm,
            height=15cm,
            %%%%%%%%%%  esthétique des axes  %%%%%%%%%%
            axis x line = bottom,
            axis y line = left,
            %enlargelimits=false,
            line width=0.35mm,
            every major grid/.append style={black!20, line width=0.35mm,},
            every minor grid/.append style={black!10, line width=0.005mm,},
            every major tick/.append style={line width=0.4 mm, major tick length=7pt, black},
            every minor tick/.append style={line width=0.01mm, minor tick length=4pt, black},
            axis background/.style={fill=white},
            }
        }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Variable %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  Coordonnée des barres
%   (#1, #2) ==> 
%   #1=l'abscisse de la barre ; 
%   #2=L'ordonnée -(/hauteur) de la barre.

\newcommand{\listep}{(1, 43) 
                    (2, 32) 
                    (3, 15)
                    (4, 12)
                    (5, 23)
                    }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[graphpgf]
\begin{axis}[
            %%%     Paramètre graphique de l'histogramme
            histogram,
            ybar,
            enlarge x limits=0.1,
            %%%     Paramètre des axes
            title style= inner sep=16pt,
            title= \Large Moyen de transport utilisés par 125 élève pour se rendre à l'école,
            %yticklabels={-5,0,5,...,45},
            ytick={-5,0,5,...,45},
            xtick=data,
            xticklabels={
                Transport en \\commun, 
                Voiture, 
                Train, 
                Vélo, 
                Marche
                },
            xticklabel style={align=center},
            xlabel=Notes des élèves,
            ylabel=Nombre d'élèves,
            xmin=1-0.25, xmax=5+0.25,
            ymin=0, ymax=45,
            %minor x tick num = 0,
            minor y tick num = 4,
            %area style,
            %xmajorgrids=true,
            %xminorgrids=true
            ymajorgrids=true,
            yminorgrids=true,
            bar width = .8cm
            ]
            \addplot+[mark=no, orange, fill=orange!50!white] plot coordinates {\listep};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```